# Does the game pick up the pace at some point?

Tags: lost-planet-3

So, I've been playing Lost Planet 3 for about 2 hours doing the introductory missions and side-quests, but it seems 90% of the time is spent slowly walking to objectives through completely safe areas. Should I expect the rest of the game to be as uneventful as the first 2 hours, or does walking slowly get phased out after I do it enough? Perhaps a fast travel system of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

Lost Planet 3 is built around a sort of interconnected series of environments with what eventually becomes a couple of primary hubs — there’s even a fast-travel system available a few hours in.

Fast-travel unlocks when you’ve actually discovered enough of the map to make it worth while.

Comment: Will I still need to walk for 5 minutes in one direction from a hub entrance to a hub point of interest and back again though?

Comment: @kotekzot Kinda. During one point, as you leave the Coronis, the option to fast-travel will be made
available. You will need to press BACK/SELECT to enter the fast-travel menu. So fast-travel isn't available everywhere.